# How to associate data to the elements in a collection without modifying the elements?

Tags: java, design-patterns

usually, when I'm doing OpenGL programming, I have a Mesh class like this:

```
public class Mesh {

    // General 3D stuff
    List<Vector3f> vertices = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Vector3f> normals = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Vector2f> texCoords = new ArrayList<>();

    // OpenGL-specific stuff
    protected int vertices;
    protected boolean dirty;
    protected int vertexArrayID = -1;
    protected int vertexBufferID = -1;

    ...

}
```

However, the application I'm working on right now is much more general, and I'd like to keep the OpenGL-specific stuff separate from the general 3D stuff. For example, someone might want to store the Mesh as an STL file and have it 3D-printed, or send it off to a Raytrace renderer to make it look nice. In that case, the OpenGL-specific data is useless.

In other words, this implementation of the Mesh class violates the single responsibility principle.

Now, one solution I can think of is the following:

```
public class Mesh {

    // General 3D stuff
    List<Vector3f> vertices = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Vector3f> normals = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Vector2f> texCoords = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class GlMesh extends Mesh implements GlDrawable {

    // OpenGL-specific stuff
    protected int vertices;
    protected boolean dirty;
    protected int vertexArrayID = -1;
    protected int vertexBufferID = -1;
}
```

However, now there are still OpenGL-specific objects in the datastructure that is output from the algorithm that generates it. The Mesh generator needs to know it should create a `GlMesh` rather than a `Mesh`, and thus knows about the OpenGL rendering module, something I'd really rather avoid.

Now, we can do something like this:

```
public class Mesh {

    // General 3D stuff
    List<Vector3f> vertices = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Vector3f> normals = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Vector2f> texCoords = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class GlMesh {

    // OpenGL-specific stuff
    protected int vertices;
    protected boolean dirty;
    protected int vertexArrayID = -1;
    protected int vertexBufferID = -1;
}

Map<Mesh, GlMesh> meshToGlMesh = (whatever)
```

However, now the rendering system has to do extensive bookkeeping to map the Mesh to the corresponding GlMesh, which is just asking for trouble.

Is there a good way to solve this that I'm missing?

Comment: What about passing the Mesh in GlMesh constructor?

Comment: That doesn't quite work. The renderer gets a list of meshes as input, and has to find the GLMesh that goes with each element in it to avoid creating the GLMesh over and over. However, what you suggest works backwards, it allows you to find the mesh easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an OpenGL programmer, so I don't know all the concerns on that front and therefore might be leading you astray, but given what you've described, it sounds like you're looking for a Factory pattern.

If your `GLMesh` object needs to be used as if it were a `Mesh`, then it needs to extend `Mesh`, obviously (or there needs to be a *facade* class in front of the `GLMesh` that makes it look like a `Mesh`).

Meanwhile, there will exist code you write that knows a `GLMesh` needs to be used. That code can pass a `GLMeshFactory` to the code that *doesn't* know it's going to work with `GLMesh`, but *does* know it needs to work with `Mesh`. It will get its `Mesh` instances from a `MeshFactory` - customarily a method called `getInstance()`, taking whatever arguments you expect any `MeshFactory` to need in order to return an instance (you'll need to think ahead - worst case, you pass it a `Map` at the end with any extra data aside from what you know any `Mesh` would need).

The `MeshFactory` can generate `Mesh` instances whatever way you're probably doing it now. The `GLMeshFactory` can just return the same instance over and over (you implied in a comment that they're expensive to create). Factories are commonly understood to return shared instances whenever appropriate.

Comment: Interesting approach, I'll be sure to try that. Yes, it does seem inevitable that the scene graph actually contains GLMesh objects of some kind, but Factory seems to be the least bad solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
public class Mesh implements GlMeshSupplier{  
    private final List<Vector3f> vertices = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<Vector3f> normals = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<Vector2f> texCoords = new ArrayList<>();

    private GlMesh glMesh;

    @Override
    public GlMesh getGlMesh() {
        return glMesh;
    }

    public void createGlMesh(){
        glMesh = new GlMesh();
    }    

    public List<Vector3f> getVertices() {
        return vertices;
    }

    public List<Vector3f> getNormals() {
        return normals;
    }

    public List<Vector2f> getTexCoords() {
        return texCoords;
    }

    public class GlMesh extends Mesh{
        // OpenGL-specific stuff
        protected int ivertices;
        protected boolean dirty;
        protected int vertexArrayID = -1;
        protected int vertexBufferID = -1;

        private GlMesh(){}

        @Override
        public List<Vector3f> getVertices() {
            return Mesh.this.vertices;
        }

        @Override
        public List<Vector3f> getNormals() {
            return Mesh.this.normals;
        }

        @Override
        public List<Vector2f> getTexCoords() {
            return Mesh.this.texCoords;
        }
    }

}

public interface GlMeshSupplier {
    public GlMesh getGlMesh();
}
```

alternative mapping between Mesh and GlMesh:

```
    //class Mesh
    public Mesh(){
        this.vertices = new ArrayList<>();
        this.normals = new ArrayList<>();
        this.texCoords = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private Mesh(List<Vector3f> vertices, List<Vector3f> normals, List<Vector2f> texCoords){
        this.vertices = vertices;
        this.normals = normals;
        this.texCoords = texCoords;
    }

    //class GlMesh
    private GlMesh(){
        super(Mesh.this.vertices, Mesh.this.normals, Mesh.this.texCoords);
    }
```

Your `Mesh` and `GlMesh` seem to be very tightly related to each other which could justify to make a composition like this. `Mesh` can be created independently from its `GlMesh`. Once `GlMesh` is created it maps (also being a `Mesh`) to the attributes of the enclosing `Mesh`.

The methods `getVertices()`, `getNormals()` and `getTexCoords()` are just examples for how the same attributes can be accessed via Mesh-methods from both the `Mesh` and its `GlMesh`.

You can also mask `Mesh` with a supplier interface like `GlMeshSupplier` if you want to hide functionality in `Mesh` which shouldn't be mapped in `GlMesh`.